# How to pass column value of a dataframe in Python to Oracle SQL script

Tags: python, python-2.7, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to pass a Python dataframe column value in a SQL script's 'where' clause?

I am trying to run a Oracle SQL script in Python. I have a dataframe df1 with columns [Week, RUN]. I would like to run the SQL script with 'where' clause containing run_number = RUN[i]. I am having a 'for' loop in Python with multiple cur.execute(sql_query) statements. In one of the 'sql_query', I have 2 'where' clauses where I have to filter out a run_number. However, I am getting 'bind variables are not supported in DDL statements' error. What is the solution to this?

```
for i in range(len(df1['RUN'])):
    cur.execute(sql_query_1, (int(df1['RUN'][i]), int(df1['RUN'][i])))
    cur.execute(sql_query_2)

sql_query_1 ='''Create table ....
where E.CID=A.CID AND :1 BETWEEN E.RUN_START AND E.RUN_END AND RUN = :2 
'''
```

I am expecting the 'for' loop to run over all RUN values, running a bunch of queries which produce certain sets of temporary tables and append to a final dataframe object in Python.

Comment: Your filtration criteria is not clear at all `where E.CID=A.CID AND :1 BETWEEN E.RUN_START AND E.RUN_END AND RUN = :2 `

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below:

```
for i in range(len(df1['RUN'])):
    cur.execute(sql_query_1, m=int(df1['RUN'][i]), n=int(df1['RUN'][i]))
    cur.execute(sql_query_2)

sql_query_1 ='''Create table ....
where E.CID=A.CID AND E.RUN_START between :m and :n and E.RUN_END between :m and:n
'''
```